# Coupled differential equation using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

[image]I am using mathematica to solve a coupled differential equation using NDSOlve and stuck with it. Could you please help me out to figure out the solution. My problem is

$$
A[\omega]:= A''[r]+\frac{f'[r]}{f[r]}A'[r]+\frac{\omega^2}{f[r]^2}-\frac{\mu^2}{f[r]}A[r]+\frac{\mu}{I \omega}S[r]=0
$$,
$$ S''[r] + \frac{f'[r]}{f[r]}S'[r] + \frac{\omega^2}{f[r]^2}S[r]-
  \frac{1}{U[r]^2} h[r]=0
$$
and $$
S[r]=\frac{I \omega}{f[r]}(\mu A[r]+h'[r]-h[r])
$$

Comment: "stuck with it" - can you show the code you used?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: OP also has network issues...

Answer (score 2):

Too long for comment:
There's a difference between equation `==` and setting a variable`=`.
In the `NDSolve[]` you appear to be "setting" `h[0]=1`
You need to change this to an equation `==`, then quit the kernel (so that `h[0]` is "unset", and try running the code again.

As you failed to provide the code I cannot check if this is sufficient to run the code smoothly.

I would also like to advise you that it is considered bad form to use single capital letter variables like `A`.

Comment: Good eye, spotting `=` ...